# selecting selected text in select option driven from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to get my SELECT box to take the selected value based on a mysql database.

It currently fills the select box up with the database and I have seen quite a few examples on the net about how to do this but I can't seem to get mine to work without making it a php echo. This confuses the life out of me and now I don't know where to put the if statement.

Here is my code so far:

```
<td><select onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_self')" name="cs" id="cs">
<option value='0'>---Select One---</option>

<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM users");
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<option value=handover.php?user=' . $line['id'] . '&log=' .$row['logid'] . '>' . $line['name'] . '</option>';
    }
}?>
```

Can anyone suggest how I can get the current value to be selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
$id_to_make_selected = // set default value here... does it come from the URL, session etc?
```

Then...

```
echo '<option value="handover.php?user=' . $line['id'] . '&log=' .$row['logid'] . '"';
echo ($line['id'] == $id_to_make_selected) ? ' selected' : '';
echo '>' . $line['name'] . '</option>';
```

Comment: It is the $id_to_make_selected bit that I am trying to work out how to get to. It needs to look at the DB and look at the $line['name'] of $line['id'] and that should be the selected one.